# How can I make this 'Elevator Door' animation with appearing text more smooth?

Tags: css, css-animations

I am currently struggling on a potentially nice animation effect. I came close to what I want, but the animation ends abruptly and in an ugly way plus it moves only to one side.

What I want to achieve is some kind of "Elevator Door" effect on my text. I only have two initials "CV" which should move apart of each other as the remaining text fades in. This is what I got so far:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.fade-in {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: textFadeIn 2s linear;
}

@keyframes textFadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 6em;
  }
}

.highlight {
  color: cyan;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="cvPrimary"><span class="highlight bold">C</span><span class="fade-in">urriculum </span>
    <span class="highlight bold">V</span><span class="fade-in">itae</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

I am not sure how I can get this right. I don't find any suitable property that would allow me to let the black-colored text take progressively more space without being visible already and in a way where *C* and *V* move apart rather symmetrically in a smooth way.

Comment: You want the V to move? Letters are added after the V rather than before so moving away from the center like the C in Curriculum does won't work.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but it should move a little as with the text next to the 'C' appearing it wouldn't be centered anymore. Yet the C moves way too far and then it ruberbands together.

Answer (score 1):

max-width animation can do a good job here:

```css
.cvPrimary {
  text-align: center
}

.cvPrimary span {
  max-width: 20px; /* you may have to adjust this */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: transparent;
  animation: textFadeIn 2s 0.5s forwards
}

.cvPrimary span:first-letter {
  color: cyan;
}

@keyframes textFadeIn {
  70% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    max-width: 200px; /* a big value here */
    color: #000
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="cvPrimary">
  <span >Curriculum </span>
  <span >Vitae</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very good try.
Let's investigate why your issue was happened.

1. Why does only the C letter move left and the V keeps its place while animating?

   [image]

   As you can see on this screenshot, the left C block and right V block are growing at the same speed, in this case C can move to left but V can't because h1 block is already centered inside container.
2. Why does the animation end abruptly?

   After the animation ends, the CSS style return to state like no animation originally. So if style of end animation and no animation are different, what will happen? style will suddenly be changed from end animation to no animation. This is solved with `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Let's go to the solution

1. First of all, we should have accurate width of each fade-in block on keyframe animation. so we should have 2 keyframes, one is for left-side(C), other is for right-side(V)

   ```css
   .content {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
       }

       .fade-in {
         display: inline-block;
         animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         animation-duration: 2s;
         animation-timing-function: linear;
         overflow: hidden;
         vertical-align: bottom;
       }

       .fade-in.left-side {
         animation-name: textFadeInLeft;
       }

       .fade-in.right-side {
         animation-name: textFadeInRight;
       }

       @keyframes textFadeInLeft {
         0% {
           opacity: 0;
           max-width: 0;
         }
         90% {
           opacity: 0;
         }
         100% {
           opacity: 1;
           max-width: 4.375em;
         }
       }

       @keyframes textFadeInRight {
         0% {
           opacity: 0;
           max-width: 0;
           /*margin-right: 70px;*/
         }
         90% {
           opacity: 0;
         }
         100% {
           opacity: 1;
           max-width: 1.5625em;
           /*margin-right: 0;*/
         }
       }

       .highlight {
         color: cyan;
       }

       .bold {
         font-weight: bold;
         display: inline-block;
         vertical-align: bottom;
       }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="content">
     <h1 class="cvPrimary"><span class="highlight bold">C</span><span class="fade-in left-side">urriculum </span>
       <span class="highlight bold">V</span><span class="fade-in right-side">itae</span>
     </h1>
   </div>
   ```

   Even though, the moving speed of C and V is different because for C and V, moving distance is different each other.

[image]

What will be solution for this?

2. If animation end block should be centered inside container, we should adjust initial position of CV, so that it will be located at the center of animation end C and V position.

[image]

This will be achieved by margin right for the right V block.

```css
.content {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .fade-in {
      display: inline-block;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      overflow: hidden;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    .fade-in.left-side {
      animation-name: textFadeInLeft;
    }

    .fade-in.right-side {
      animation-name: textFadeInRight;
    }

    @keyframes textFadeInLeft {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        max-width: 0;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        max-width: 4.375em;
      }
    }

    @keyframes textFadeInRight {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        max-width: 0;
        margin-right: 70px;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        max-width: 1.5625em;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    }

    .highlight {
      color: cyan;
    }

    .bold {
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="cvPrimary"><span class="highlight bold">C</span><span class="fade-in left-side">urriculum </span>
    <span class="highlight bold">V</span><span class="fade-in right-side">itae</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

And I used flex layout instead of grid layout. you can switch it as grid layout, I tested it works properly with grid layout. But I recommend to use flex layout.

You may feel this is a little bit "hardcoded", but in my experience, there is no good result without much effort.